# BASH conditional if statement ANDing two commands that output true or false

Tags: bash, if-statement

In BASH, I have an if statement like so:

`if dokku ps:report $APP_NAME --deployed && ! dokku certs:report $APP_NAME --ssl-enabled; then echo "works"; fi`

Each command outputs `true` or `false`. I want the `then` clause to get executed when the first command outputs `true` and the second outputs `false` (which is why I have the `!`). But when I run this, it outputs:

```
true
false
```

If I run the second command individually:

```
dokku certs:report $APP_NAME --ssl-enabled
```

It outputs `false`. So the negation in my original if statement isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
if echo false
then
  echo "Why does this print?"
fi
```

This is because the command output is irrelevant. `if`, `&&` and `||` all look at the command's *exit code*. They don't try to interpret English text.

You can instead use string comparison:

```
if [ "$(dokku ps:report $APP_NAME --deployed)" = "true" ] && [ "$(dokku certs:report $APP_NAME --ssl-enabled)" = "false" ]
then ...
```